# Sob! Why don't you model.RememberMe? How do I configure in MVC 5 login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, session-cookies

So I know the LoginViewModel model.RememberMe is coming in through the default Login that comes with VS 2013. But it is not being set. Not sure where to set it from false to true and to make use of it. Below is where I think the setting should be. Something like a cookie . . . no?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);


    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here is the checkbox on the Login View. It has to be checked manually. Where would this get set?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your login view. could be that you are not setting the remember me value on the client/view

Comment: Unless the user checks the checkbox then it will remain false. If you want it to be selected by default. you can set the `model.RememberMe` in the get of the login action. But remember the user can manually uncheck this if they want

Comment: I get that an unchecked checkbox remains false. It is an age old problem to deal with. My problem is I can't find where a true or false value for the model.RememberMe cookie gets saved. I can't find the code. Would be nice to know what folder the cookie is saved in also. If there is one there, then maybe this is working.

Comment: Use fiddler or some other tool to inspect what cookie is sent with the response